# How do you refer to items in a list?

Tags: numbers, counters

Given a list of things...

1. dog
2. cat
3. fish

How would you say...

1. *the second item in the list*: ２目番?
2. *all three of them*: 全部三つ?
3. *two of them* (not regarding the position in the list): ２匹 or ２目?

Is this pattern correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there. ~全部{ぜんぶ}3つ~ sounds definitely off, but 3つ全部{ぜんぶ} is fine.

### The first, the second, the third...

- 一番目{いちばんめ}、二番目{にばんめ}、三番目{さんばんめ} *Slightly* more formal tone.
- 1つ目{め}、2つ目{め}、3つ目{め} *Slightly* more casual tone, perhaps used more often between people of equal / similar status.

### All 3 of them, all of them

- 3つとも
- これらすべて
- 3つすべて
- 全部

#### If there were 2 items

- 2つとも
- 両方{りょうほう}

> **Note:** In this case you wouldn't say すべて or 全部

### Two of them

- これらのうち2つ
- このうち（の）2つ

---

### How do you say 1つ、2つ、3つ...?

- 1つ → ひとつ
- 2つ → ふたつ
- 3つ → み**っ**つ
- 4つ → よ**っ**つ
- 5つ → いつつ
- 6つ → む**っ**つ
- 7つ → ななつ
- 8つ → や**っ**つ
- 9つ → ここのつ
- 10 → じゅ**っ**こ

#### What about 10【とお】?

The old pronunciation とお is to all intents and purposes never used in spoken conversation. For numbers after 10 you would resort to じゅっこ、じゅういっこ、じゅうにこ...

- じゅっこすべて
- じゅっことも
- このうち（の）じゅっこ

Answer (score 3):

"the second item in the list" -> 2番目
"all three of them" -> 3つ全部 or 3つとも
"two of them" -> これらのうち2つ or これらのうち2匹

Answer (score 1):

２番目 is OK.

> two of them (not regarding the position in the list) ２匹 or ２目...

両方{りょうほう} is definitely the best.

> all three of them 全部三つ

全部{ぜんぶ} is probably used the more

---

- 2つとも and 3つとも would be a second best.
- すべて usually comes after the word like in これ(ら)すべて, 3,4,5つすべて。